# @ being converted into string when passing in the URL

Tags: jquery, urlencode, window.open

I am trying to post data to a URL through HTTP request, when I try to pass email then it converts **@** into **%252540**.

Here is the URL:

```
window.open('https://secure.rspcdn.com/xprr/red/PID/3428/SID/rentown?email=amrinder@odz.com');
```

Please take a look at the given fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/amrindernoor/b8uvwr86/

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: What does `php` tag do here?

Comment: I think your new tab has a redirection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL `https://secure.rspcdn.com/xprr/red/PID/3428/SID/rentown?email=amrinder@odz.com` has multiple internal redirects.

In each redirect, it encodes the already encoded email.

Here is the brief explanation on what exactly is causing the issue:

> At first, `@` is passed as it is.
>
> During first redirection, it is encoded to `%40` which is still valid.
>
> Here after in each redirection, it gets encoded again resulting in `%252540` as the final value.

Below is the screen shot that will give you a clear picture on this

[image]

Comment: ah! got it, but what's the solution now? as i don't have access of the server where the second redirection exists.

Comment: There is no other solution other than contacting concerned person to grant you access so that encoding stuff can be fixed from root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent` for the email address parameter:

```
window.open('https://secure.rspcdn.com/xprr/red/PID/3428/SID/rentown?email=' + encodeURIComponent('amrinder@odz.com'))
```

The correct value for the email parameter (returned by encodeURIComponent) is ˙amrinder%40odz.com˙, which will be interpreted as `amrinder@odz.com` server-side.

After the change, that URL returns a 302 redirect to `https://www.rsptrack.com/click.track?CID=287283&AFID=276422&SID=rentown&SID2=n&SID3=n&email=amrinder%40odz.com&zid=f197f1cfb16ae7d56748bca35ebe7658&tkp=3428&tku=4160&tks=86073803`, which seems to contains the correct value for the email parameter.

Comment: i have tried this, no help, you can also try the same in the fiddle provided by me.

Comment: still same result, here is the updated version of fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b8uvwr86/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function to get it done. This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`

```
window.open('https://secure.rspcdn.com/xprr/red/PID/3428/SID/rentown?email=' + encodeURIComponent('amrinder@odz.com'))
```

**Note :**

> Use the [decodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) function to decode an encoded URI
>   component.